# Digit count function for C programming won't work past 11 digits

Tags: c

The following function is supposed to be used to count the number of digits in a number. Unfortunately it doesn't work for numbers with 11 or more digits and I'm not sure why. I feel like it has something to do with the data type but I thought long long int would be fine in this case. Thanks for the help!

```
long long int getLength(long long int input)
{
  long long int length = 0;

  while(input != 0)
  {
    input /= 10;
    ++length;
  }
  return (length);
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a very good diagnostic. What doesn't work? You see wrong results, the program crashes, the program hangs?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverfow. The size may depend on your compiler and if your computer is 32 or 64bit. A 32-bit unsigned int has a range from 0 to 4,294,967,295. 0 to 65535 would be a 16-bit unsigned. An unsigned long long on a 64-bit implementation have a range  0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: `2^32 = 4. * 10^9` and `2^64 = 1. * 10^19` so it looks like `long long` is 32 bits for your env, which is odd. Or maybe there is a cast somewhere to a narrower data type before calling the function ...

Comment: If you need to find the length of _any_ integer provided as a string, just read it as a string.

Comment: Rather than looping through the value or converting it to a string, you could return the integer portion of 1 + the base 10 logarithm of the number.

Comment: 1) "t doesn't work for numbers with 11 or more digit" because of the code that is calling `getLength()`.  Post an [mcve].  2) `getLength(0)` returns 0 when 1 is more often expected.

Comment: @DavidFletcher Directly using log fails when `input <= 0` and `log10(x)` has quality of implementation issues that can render the floating point results problematic for an integer problem.  The log approach is easy to code wrong for cases of `input` near powers of 10.  Aside from 0, OP's approach is fine.  The calling code is in error.

Comment: the return type doesn't need to be `long long` since the length of a `long long` fits even in a byte. So you can just return an `int`

Comment: A `long long` can represent at least 17 decimal digits, so your code should have no problems.   Odds are the caller is converting to and from a 32-bit type which is, generally speaking, is not always able to represent more than nine decimal digits.    Without code demonstrating how the function is called, nobody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not stand as an answer, but allow me to report output here. Can you double check? It *works* on my side.

```
#include "stdio.h"

long long int getLength(long long int input)
{
  long long int length = 0;

  while(input != 0)
  {
    input /= 10;
    ++length;
  }
  return (length);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%lld\n", getLength(12345678901));   // 11
    printf("%lld\n", getLength(123456789012));  // 12
    printf("%lld\n", getLength(1234567890123)); // 13
    printf("%lld\n", getLength(0));             // 0
    printf("%lld\n", getLength(-123));          // 3
}
```

Platform Windows 10, and `gcc --version` returns

```
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0
```

Question 1: do you really need type `long long int` to report number of digits?

Question 2: did you correctly use the format specifier `%lld` in your `printf`?

Comment: Curious, for "to count the number of digits in a number. " do you think `getLength(0)` should return 0 or 1.  In the end, it is OP's call, just wondering about your view.

Comment: @chux it should return 1 in my view

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need long long int for the length? I mean it's the length of the number, NOT the number itself.

This code works fine in my compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getLength(long long int input)
{
    int length = 0;

    while(input != 0)
    {
        input /= 10;
        ++length;
    }
    return (length);
}

int main() {

    printf("Length of number : %d\n", getLength(12345678901234));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Length of number : 14

Program ended with exit code: 0
```